# How to listen to midi events from Aksequencer

Tags: midi, xcode11, audiokit, coremidi

I am playing a MIDI file from the new AKSequencer but I don't know how I can listen to the midi events that the sequencer plays with an AKMIDIListener.

The end of my question is to create a MIDI player with which I can send the data to another instrument with a midi IN port or to a CoreMIDI compatible RTP-MIDI server.

Comment: Sorry but they did not intend to pass me the code for a complete project. Only that in audiokit 4.9.1 the AKsequencer has been updated and I do not know how to obtain, while playing the midi file, the midi events to trigger actions with the AKMIDIListener. Sorry but you didn't mean that. He saw all the playgrounds and examples for IOS but none of the AKsequencer and AKMIDIListener are implemented.

Answer (score 0):

AKSequencer was renamed to AKAppleSequencer. And from the source code of AudioKit, the function `setGlobalMIDIOutput` is not implemented in the actual `AKSequencer` yet. I suggest you to use `AKAppleSequencer` instead.